# How to destruct a function (like H : ~ (forall x : X, p x)) in Coq?

Tags: coq

I've been trying to prove a Lemma in Coq that like this,

```
Goal forall (X : Type) (p : X -> Prop), 
(exists x, ~ p x) <-> ~ (forall x, p x).
```

This is my attempt at it,

```
Proof.
  intros X p. split.
  - intros [x B] C. apply B. apply C.
  - simpl. intros H.
```

I got stuck, with this.

```
1 subgoal
X : Type
p : X -> Prop
H : ~ (forall x : X, p x)
______________________________________(1/1)
exists x : X, ~ p x
```

And now, my thinking is that maybe i could destruct H in a certain way to progress. Or maybe there's a better way of finishing this? Please help, thanks in advance!

Comment: You need classical logic to prove this direction (the law of excluded middle or double negation elimination or any other equivalent formula).

Comment: So, I can try asserting a new function that will H into forall x:X, ~px?

Comment: This is related to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35518303/is-this-relationship-between-forall-and-exists-provable-in-coq-intuitionistic-lo

Comment: @Lolo So does that mean that this is unprovable?

Comment: It is unprovable in the base logic of Coq, however it is not a problem to extend the logic with excluded middle and prove it; but it makes sense the base logic of Coq is more general as to also accomodate worlds that conflict with classical axioms.

Answer (score 0):

yep, you need an extra axiom
If you do :

```
Require Import Classical.
Check classic.
```

now using `classic`, you can do the proof.